# Convergence of Real Number sequences

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

(a) Suppose {$a_n$} $  \rightarrow a$. Let {$b_n$} be the sequence defined by:

$\hspace{70mm} $$b_n = \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}$

Show that {$b_n$} $\rightarrow$ $a$

(b) Let $a_n$ = {$(-1^n)$}. Show that {$a_n$} diverges, but the sequence {$b_n$} defined by:

$\hspace{70mm} $$b_n = \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}$

converges.

For part (a) I find myself asking "what do we know about {$a_n$}?" If {$a_n$} converges to $a$  , then we know that for any $\epsilon$ greater than zero, there is some positive integer $N$($\epsilon$) such that if $n$ is a positive integer larger than $N$($\epsilon$), then $|${$a_n$} - $a$$|$ $<$ $\epsilon$.

Now, thinking back to class time, I'm reminded of the numerous inequalities we went over. I figure here, we might be able to prove {$b_n$} $\rightarrow$ $a$ by introducing an inequality, say {$a_n$} $>$ {$b_n$} and working from there.

For Part (b). I know {$(-1^n)$} diverges because the limits do not match up from odd to even integers $n$. For {$b_n$}, I fail to see how the limit for {$b_n$} would converge since it is dependent upon {$a_n$}. Am I thinking of this in the wrong fashion?

Answer (score 1):

As for a) the proof is known as Cesaro theorem and can be found here at MSE in previous posts. For b) a(2n+1) = - 1 --> -1 as n --> infinity and a(2n) = 1 --> 1 as n goes to infinity.This means it has 2 subsequences converge to different values so it diverges. And b(n) = 0 if n is even and b(n) = -1/n if n is odd. So /b(n)/ <= 1/n for all n's so -1/n < b(n) < 1/n and using squeeze theorem to get lim b(n) = 0 and it converges to 0.

Comment: Seriously? I looked for part a). Is there a more efficient way to search MSE? I just could not find an example close to my question.

Comment: Look also for Stolz, sometimes only one of the names is given. The theorem is about Cesaro summation, which gives the Dirichlet kernel in Fourier series theory.